# Type synonym instance

Tags: haskell

Reading "Category Theory for Programmers" I am trying to recreate the Functor typeclass instance for Op.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}

module Type.Op where

import Data.Functor.Contravariant ( Contravariant, contramap )

type Op r a = a -> r
-- data Op r a = (->) a r

instance Contravariant (Op r) where
    contramap f g = g . f
```

The compilation produces the following error:

```
    • The type synonym ‘Op’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given 1
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Contravariant (Op r)’
   |
10 | instance Contravariant (Op r) where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What should I do ? For the normal `Functor` I would have used a partial type the same way...

Comment: Type synonyms must appear 'fully saturated' in instance heads. Which is what the message is telling you. There's a few places where you can 'partially apply' type synonyms, but instance heads are not one of those.

Comment: @AntC could elaborate on where type synonyms can be partially applied? AFAIK they *always* have to be saturated, so one has to use a newtype to wrap them and make partial application possible.

Comment: @atleastgetyourjabs https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/liberal_type_synonyms.html at "* You can apply a type synonym to a partially applied type synonym". So the partially-applied can appear only inside a call to another synonym that fully-applies it during 'macro expansion'.

Comment: See also [Can I write a higher order type for a -> b -> *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44191123/791604).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that type synonyms are **not** types in their own right. They merely allow you to give new labels to existing things, and then talk about them using the labels instead of referring to them directly.

Type synonyms are completely transparent to most type system features, which can only work by substituting the definition of the synonym. A type synonym isn't a thing that "really exists" in order to have a class instance or not. That's why vanilla Haskell doesn't let you declare instances using type synonyms at all.

The `TypeSynonymInstances` extension doesn't actually change this fundamental picture; all it does is let you declare instances for the underlying types used in the definition of a synonym, but using the synonym to refer to it. That sentence was a mouthful; example time:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

data List a = a `Cons` List a | Nil

type Str = List Char

instance Eq Str
  where x `Cons` xs == y `Cons` ys
          = x == y && xs == ys
        Nil == Nil = True
        _ == _ = False
```

Here I've defined a new list type, and a new string synonym (much like the built in `type String = [Char]`, but I didn't want existing instances to get in the way). Then I declared `instance Eq Str`. But this **doesn't** really make an instance for `Str`; it makes an instance for `List Char`. All `TypeSynonymInstances` did was let me use my label `Str` as a standin for writing `List Char` in the instance declaration; nothing more. The results are exactly the same as if I *had* written `instance Eq (List Char)`. You can clearly see the distinction when I then do something like this:

```
isEmpty :: Eq (List a) => List a -> Bool
isEmpty xs = xs == Nil
```

The definition of `isEmpty` needs an `Eq (List a)` instance, but it doesn't itself know about `Str` or `Char`. This should not be usable if `instance Str` was somehow different than `instance (List Char)`. But with no other instances declared, I can still call `` isEmpty ('x' `Cons` Nil) ``; GHC doesn't even need me to say whether I consider that a `List Char` or a `Str` because they are the same thing, and `Eq Str` is the same thing as `Eq (List Char)`.

If you think about it, defining a type synonym and then wanting to give it its own instances (separate from the underlying type) is a little bit like trying to say "let x = 5, and then we'll define what negation means for x by saying -x = -50". x isn't a new thing, it's just a name for 5. x neither needs nor can have its own definition of negation, because 5 already has one.

Now, lets bring this back to the OP's `Op` type synonym. Synonyms are allowed to be more complicated than just a label for an existing type; they can be *parameterised* labels, like `type Op r a = a -> r`. However it's still fundamentally true that `Op` "doesn't really exist". Any time I use `Op Foo Bar` I'm really just talking about `Bar -> Foo`. And there is no sense in which instances for `Op` can actually exist; only instances for the underlying type constructor `->` that is used in its definition.

For example, this fails with a duplicate instance error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleContexts, InstanceSigs #-}

type Op r a = a -> r

class Silly t
  where silly :: t -> Bool

instance Silly (a -> r)
  where silly :: (a -> r) -> Bool
        silly _ = True

instance Silly (Op r a)
  where silly = False
```

`Op r a` already has an instance for `Silly`, because `a -> r` has one. I can't make any instances for `Op` that I don't want regular `->` to have, and vice versa.

Now lets consider `instance Contravariant (Op r)`. This can't "really" be declaring an instance for `Op r`, only for the thing that's a synonym for. So we need something to substitute for `Op r` to know what instance we're declaring, but what? `Op r a` is well-defined; it means `a -> r`. But to expand just `Op r` we need to be able to partially apply `->` to its *second* argument. That's not something you can even really express directly in Haskell<sup>1</sup>. So it's *certainly* not something you can make an instance of a type class.

To avoid problems like this, type synonyms must be supplied with all of their parameters. This means that the compiler can "look through" the synonym to see what types you're really talking about. Partially applied type synonyms aren't guaranteed to be meaningful at all, so GHC normally forbids them.<sup>2</sup> In the cases where a partially applied synonym *could* expand to something sensible, you just have to write the expansion yourself to declare an instance.

In cases like this where the partially applied synonym *can't* expand to something sensible, you just can't declare the instance. You *can* always use a `newtype` rather than a type synonym; since these create real new types, not just labels for existing types, there's no problem with them being partially applied:

```
newtype Op r a = Op { getOp :: a -> r }

instance Contravariant (Op r) where
  contramap :: (a' -> a) -> (Op r a -> Op r a')
  contramap f g = Op (getOp g . f)
```

A new type is what you need anyway if you don't want the underlying type constructor to also get the instance (i.e. you want an instance for `Op` without also making an instance for `->`).

Indeed, the `Data.Functor.Contravariant` module already defines `Op` as a `newtype` (and this `Contravariant` instance), precisely because the class system can only work with partial application of type constructors "in the right order". `Op` only exists to be a version of `->` that takes its parameters in the opposite order so that instances can be declared. If partial application of `->` to its second argument was possible, there would be no need for `Op`, we'd just write something like:

```
instance Contravariant (-> r)
  where contramap f g = g . f
```

Then we'd be able to write `fmap (+1) func` or `contramap (+1) func` depending on whether we wanted to post-process func's result with `(+1)` or pre-process func's argument with `(+1)`. But Haskell's type system does not support this.

---

<sup>1</sup> At the value level we have operator sections, and so could write `(-> r)`. That's really just shorthand for a function defined as `\a -> a -> r` though, whereas we have direct syntactic support for partial application to first arguments. Regardless, we don't have operator sections at the type level, nor type-level functions for them to be shorthand for. (Type synonym families are the closest thing to type level functions we have, but you can't make partially applied type families instances of type classes either, for much the same reasons as regular type synonyms)

---

<sup>2</sup> In some contexts GHC is clever and *can* work with partially applied synonyms, if you turn on `LiberalTypeSynonyms`. It does this by basically waiting to see if the type expression the partially-applied synonym appears in eventually provides the missing arguments, so that everything becomes well defined. For example this works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LiberalTypeSynonyms #-}

type Op r a = a -> r

type OnInt f = f Int

foo :: OnInt (Op String)
-- foo :: (Op String) Int
-- foo :: Op String Int
-- foo :: Int -> String
foo x = show x
```

`Op String` isn't a well defined type expression on its own at all, but GHC temporarily ignores that and passes this "unevaluated" to `OnInt` anyway, which results in `Op String Int`, which *is* well defined so it's okay. That still doesn't mean that `Op String` is a first class type expression that we could try to make an instance for, however.

Comment: Pop quiz: what's the result for `let -5 = -50 in -5`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I... guess that must be `-5`? It's a lazy pattern match that would fail, but because no variables from it are used (it doesn't bind any) the match is never actually carried out? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It's kind of surprising though, because `let 0 - 5 = -50 in 0 - 5` yields `-50`. In that case, you're redefining the binary `-` operator, but it turns out there's no way to redefine the unary one. — Really, the awkward thing is that neither of these gives an error message!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ugh, yes, I missed the unary negation wrinkle and got the right answer by accident! Given how unary operators don't really fit Haskell very well, I almost wished they'd left it out of the original spec entirely and gone with negative literals instead. Would have meant `(-x)` is unexpectedly `\a -> a - x`, but I could probably get used to that easier.

Comment: I agree! I'm not even sure if negative literals would cause more surprises. I can't count how often I typed something like `map (-1) $ tail xs` before remembering I instead need to use the pretty unwieldy `map (subtract 1)`. Whereas `negate x` can always be written infix-ish as `0-x`, that's not much overhead.

Comment: ...hm, actually with `-XNegativeLiterals` you still need to write `map (+ -1)`, also a bit silly. I guess for the `1` case I should really just be using `pred`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Actually the newer [`LexicalNegation`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/lexical_negation.html#extension-LexicalNegation) looks pretty reasonable; you can do `map (- 1)`. And it's consistent between literals and other expressions; i.e. `(- x)` is `subtract x` and `(-x)` is `negate x`. Hadn't spotted them adding that in GHC 9 until now!

Comment: nice, wasn't aware of that at all. I've often though that using whitespace information like that would make a lot of sense. What if _any_ operator could be overloaded to a prefix form, active iff there is whitespace to the left but not to the right? At least `(/x)` ≡ `recip x` could also come in useful, and definitely (`^-^x`) ≡ [`negateV x`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html#v:negateV).

Answer (score 5):

Let's consider a simpler class

```
class Unftor f where
  unfmap :: (a -> a) -> f a -> f a

instance Unftor ((->) x) where
  unfmap f g = f . g
```

Now, if what you tried to do were possible, I could *also* write

```
instance Unftor (Op r) where
  unfmap f g = g . f
```

...but wait, let's look at the signatures in each case

```
instance Unftor ((->) x) where
  unfmap :: (a -> a) -> (x -> a) -> (x -> a)
instance Unftor (Op r) where
  unfmap :: (a -> a) -> Op r a -> Op r a
```

Since `Op` is just a type synonym, that would be the same as

```
instance Unftor (\a -> (a -> r)) where
  unfmap :: (a -> a) -> (a -> r) -> (a -> r)
```

Now, picking the special case that all types are `Int`,

```
unfmap :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
unfmap f g = f . g   -- from `instance Unftor ((->) x)`
unfmap :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
unfmap f g = g . f   -- from `instance Unftor (Op r)`
```

...the same signature! But somehow the compiler is supposed to keep them apart??

That doesn't work.

What you need to do instead is make `Op` a distinguishable type that's merely *isomorphic* to `a -> r`. That's exactly what newtypes are there for (`data` would also work):

```
newtype Op r a = Op {getOp :: a -> r}

instance Contravariant (Op r) where
    contramap (Op f) g = Op $ g . f
```